# Show Page Footer before Report Footer on Last Page in Telerik Report

Tags: asp.net, telerik, report

I am using Telerik Reporting.
My question is :

**How to show Page Footer before Report Footer on Last Page??**

I have a report in which I show Pagewise Totals and Grand Total both.
But on last page Grand total comes before Page total and I want Grand total in the end of Report and Page total come before it.

Actually in Telerik Reporting, Page Footer is always come at the end of page, even Report Footer comes before Page Footer....

[image: currently it shows like this]

I want  :

[image: what I want is like]

Can i achieve this? and How?

Thanks in Advance...

**Edit :**

Is there any suggestion to achieve similar like this from any other way ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want exactly is not possible currently.(if telerik updates than don't know.)

Because Page footer always come in the end of page, that's why it is called Page footer.
It is not related to Report Footer. Report & Page footer are two different things.

According to the [Why does the page header appear before the report header?](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/faq-report-page-header.html)
article, page sections are not related to the report itself, but are relative to the margins of the report's media. Therefore you can't switch the positions of report section and page section.

So your current logic is alright..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that. Not exactly but we could rely on that...

I have put Grand Total & Page Total both in `Page Footer`

And for Grand Total I had set a `FormattingRule` in `ConditioningFormatting` , in that I had set `Visible = True` only if `PageNumber = PageCount`

now Page Total & Grand Total both come at end of Page in Page Footer but `Grand Total` only shows in last page and after `Page Total`

Any other answer is most welcomed and appreciated...